# How to solve the error while saving a dataframe to csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was saving the dataframe as below

```
Target1_file.to_csv( r'C:\Users\para\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Data\data1\'+str(File_T1_name)+'.csv', index=True,header=True)
```

where

```
File_T1_name = str(time_.tm_mday) + str(time_.tm_mon) + str(time_.tm_year) + "_SQ12_TC12." + str(filter_index) + "T1_statistics"
```

I am getting following error:

```
Missing closing quote [']
',' or ')' expected
```

how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use f-strings instead of raw strings:

```
Target1_file.to_csv(fr"C:\Users\para\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Data\data1\{File_T1_name}.csv", index=True,header=True)
```

where

```
File_T1_name = fr"{time_.tm_mday}{time_.tm_mon}{time_.tm_year}_SQ12_TC12.{filter_index}T1_statistics"
```

Comment: i end with this error **SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

Comment: chane to Target1_file.to_csv(f"C:\\Users\\para\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\Data\\data1\\{File_T1_name}.csv", index=True,header=True)

Comment: @mathew  I edited my response. You can combine raw strings and f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could tryout is adding `".csv"` to file name variable itself

```
File_T1_name = str(time_.tm_mday) + str(time_.tm_mon) + str(time_.tm_year) + "_SQ12_TC12." + str(filter_index) + "T1_statistics" + ".csv"
```

and then use `"\\"`(double backslash) in the file path instead of `"\"`(single backslash)

```
Target1_file.to_csv('C:\\Users\\para\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\Data\data1\\' + str(File_T1_name), index=True, header=True)
```